# Integrating IdentityServer3 OpenID Connect Provider and OAuth 2.0 Authorization Server with a web forms asp.net 4.6 application

Tags: asp.net, webforms, owin, dotnetnuke, identityserver3

How can I integrate IdentityServer3 [(OpenID Connect Provider and OAuth 2.0 Authorization Server Framework)](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3)
that is based on OWIN middleware with a web forms asp.net 4.6 application like DNN CMS with its own [membership provider.](http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/membership-provider)
I would like to provide Custom Store implementation for IdentityServer3 to manager/pick DNN's users, roles, claims.

**Essentially I would like to know how can an OWIN based application interact (share some of the run time data (context) with a Web Forms Asp.net application.**

**Are we dealing with completely isolated pipelines here if I install Identity Server under the same web application?**

DotNetNuke uses a membership provider which is heavily based on the asp.net equivalent, but extends and alters it to support some additional functionality and be aware of DotNetNuke concepts such as portal isolation.You can read about the enhancements made from the asp.net provider here.

Answer (score 0):

DNN would need to support external authentications from an OIDC IdP.

Comment: Thanks Allen. So you are suggesting to have an independent host for OIDC IdP  (different IP/and or Port) and I don't have to think about integrating DNN Webforms based environment (which would act as a Client (RP) and a Resource Server ) and Identity Server. 

I could provide an IUserService implementaton based on DNN WebForms authentication which mixes old Web forms aspnet_ (users, membership, applications) and a few DNN specific user related and roles tables.

Comment: The idea here is to use already existing DNN screens for managing users, roles and permissions and expose user identity, profile, roles and some additional claims to third party client applications as well as DNN client which holds user database. 

Is this correct way to go if I am to provide Identity Server support in DNN myself?